# How to list vms by specific Azure resource group

Tags: python, virtual-machine, azure-resource-group

I am able to list VMs all within a Azure subscription.

But I am hoping to filter only listing VMs from a specific resource group.

Here is my python script:

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.common import credentials

resource_group_name = "MyResourceGroup"
# Below is a secure method of selecting the correct subscription without having to expose subID, tenantID, client_id and client_secret
CREDENTIAL = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True, exclude_visual_studio_code_credential=True, exclude_environment_credential=True, exclude_managed_identity_credential=True, 
                                        exclude_powershell_credential=True, exclude_interactive_browser_credential=True)
subscription_id = credentials.get_azure_cli_credentials()[1]
subscription_name = SubscriptionClient(CREDENTIAL).subscriptions.get(subscription_id).display_name

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(CREDENTIAL, subscription_id)
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(CREDENTIAL, subscription_id)

def list_vms_in_subscription():
    for group in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
        list_vms_in_groups(group.name)

def list_vms_in_groups(group_name):
    for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list(group_name):
        print(vm.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_vms_in_subscription()
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you try with `compute_client.virtual_machines.list(resource_group_name)`?

Comment: So when I do that, the list keeps repeating and I end up having to cancel the script run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have below list of VM's in resource group named **Identity-Resources** like this:

[image]

To list VM's by specific Azure resource group, you can make use of below ***modified*** python code as *@Abdul Niyas* suggested:

```py
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.common import credentials

resource_group_name = "Identity-Resources"
# Below is a secure method of selecting the correct subscription without having to expose subID, tenantID, client_id and client_secret
CREDENTIAL = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True, exclude_visual_studio_code_credential=True, exclude_environment_credential=True, exclude_managed_identity_credential=True, 
                                        exclude_powershell_credential=True, exclude_interactive_browser_credential=True)
subscription_id = credentials.get_azure_cli_credentials()[1]
subscription_name = SubscriptionClient(CREDENTIAL).subscriptions.get(subscription_id).display_name

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(CREDENTIAL, subscription_id)
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(CREDENTIAL, subscription_id)

def list_vms_in_resource_group(group_name):
    for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list(group_name):
        print(vm.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_vms_in_resource_group(resource_group_name)
```

**Response:**

[image]